# 'int' object has no attribute 'x'

Tags: python, class, python-3.x

I'm trying to make a program to add vectors using `__add __`:

```
class vects:
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def __add__(self, vect):
        total_x = self.x + vect.x
        total_y = self.y + vect.y
        return vects(total_x, total_y)

plusv1 = vects.__add__(2,5)
plusv2 = vects.__add__(1,7)
totalplus = plusv1 + plusv2
```

The error produced is as follows:

```
line 12, in <module> plusv1 = vects.__add__(2,5)
line 7, in __add__ total_x = self.x + vect.x
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'x'
```

Comment: The function you're using should be used as follow from what I've understood of your code: `vects.__add__(vects(2, 5))` and not `vects.__add__(2, 5)` as the __add__ definition is waiting for only 1 argument which seems to be another instance of the vects class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't use `__add__` like that! :-) `__add__` will get implicitly invoked when `+` is used on an instance of the `Vects` class.

So, what you should first do is initialize two vector instances:

```
v1 = Vects(2, 5)
v2 = Vects(1, 7)
```

and then add them:

```
totalplus = v1 + v2
```

If you add a nice `__str__` to get a nice representation of your new vector:

```
class Vects:
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def __add__(self, vect):
        total_x = self.x + vect.x
        total_y = self.y + vect.y
        return Vects(total_x, total_y)

    def __str__(self):
        return "Vector({}, {})".format(self.x, self.y)
```

You can get a view of `totalplus` by printing it:

```
print(totalplus)
Vector(3, 12)
```

Comment: I however would not say that calling the `__add__` method from a class by a direct call, like `MyClass.__add__(object1, object2)`, is absolutely useless. Okay, Python is not really designed for such things, but it could be used in a really complex casting case, with multiple inheritance, where one would want to call the `__add__` method of another class. For some reason. It can happen. Faster than you think. I guess.

Comment: And of course if you want to have a good programming style (see [PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)) the class should be called `Vector`.

Comment: @Rightleg not sure about the use case; and for the puproses of multiple inheritance you'd never want to hard-code a class name (thats one of the reasons `super` exists.) I'm not arguing that a use-case might not exist, just that this isn't one so no need to confuse OP without reason.

Comment: @JimFasarakis-Hilliard Yeah, that's why I refrained from posting this as an answer xD